# Jquery no funciona en ciclo ngFor Angular

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript

se me hace complicado hacer los querySelectorAll y traté de implementar JQuery

El siguiente código es el HTML del componente

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let key of Keys" id="key">
        <td width="40"><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="" id=""></td>
        <td width="130">{{key.line + key.code}}</td>
        <td width="250">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span name="images">
                    <div class="case">[<i class="fas fa-circle"></i>]</div>
                </span>
                <select class="form-control" id="selectColor" name="op1">
                    <option class="white"></option>
                    <option class="white">0</option>
                    <option class="gray">1</option>
                    <option class="brown">2</option>
                    <option class="blue">3</option>
                    <option class="purple">4</option>
                    <option class="green">5</option>
                </select>
                <select class="form-control" id="selectColor" name="op2">
                    <option class="white"></option>
                    <option class="white">0</option>
                    <option class="gray">1</option>
                    <option class="brown">2</option>
                    <option class="blue">3</option>
                    <option class="purple">4</option>
                    <option class="green">5</option>
                </select>
                <select class="form-control" id="selectColor" name="op3">
                    <option class="white"></option>
                    <option class="white">0</option>
                    <option class="gray">1</option>
                    <option class="brown">2</option>
                    <option class="blue">3</option>
                    <option class="purple">4</option>
                    <option class="green">5</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>{{key.desc}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Y trataba de hacer uso de Jquery en los Select y varias cosas en general, este es el código de los select

Declaré el numeral y query

```
declare const $: any;
declare const jQuery: any;
```

Y también el código de Jquery

```
public selectC(): void {
  let select = $("[id=selectColor]");
  for (let i = 0; i < select.length; i++) {
    $(select[i]).change(function () {
      var color = $("option:selected", this).attr("class");
      $(select[i]).attr("class", color).addClass("form-control");
    });
  }
}
```

Pero dejó de funcionar cuando lo metí en el ngFor

Ayuda :c

También creo que se puede hacer con una llamada de tipo ViewChild

```
@ViewChild('tbody') tbody: ElementRef;
```

Pero no quiere aunque lo ponga como parte del Jquery :c

O bueno ¿cómo puedo seleccionar elementos HTML con Angular y darles evento? :c

Comment: En qué momento llamas la función selectC()?

Comment: Pues lo intenté con ngAfterViewInit() y ngOnInit() y nada  @crrlos :c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agrega un parámetro al método selectC() y dentro del método evalúa con un if ese parámetro:

```
public selectC(ultimo): void {
  if(ultimo){
    let select = $("[id=selectColor]");
    for (let i = 0; i < select.length; i++) {
     $(select[i]).change(function () {
        var color = $("option:selected", this).attr("class");
        $(select[i]).attr("class", color).addClass("form-control");
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Modifica el ngfor para que se vea así:

```
<tr *ngFor="let key of Keys;let ultimo = last" id="key">

 <!-- resto del código removido por simplicidad -->

 {{selectC(ultimo)}}
 </tr>
```

antes del `</tr>` de cierre agrega el código `{{selectC(ultimo)}}`

**Explicación:**

Los elementos html deben existir antes de que puedan ser llamados con javascript. Por eso si llamas la función `selectC()` antes de que estén listos los elementos no funcionará. La solución que propuse llama a `selectC()` por cada iteración del `ngFor` pero se le pasa un parámetro para indicarle si ya es la última iteración, de esa forma se garantiza que todos los elementos html han sido creados y pueden ser llamados con js.

**Actualización:**

Otra forma sería llamar `selectC()` en el `ngAfterViewInit()`

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
 this.selectC();
}
```

Debería funcionar y no tienes que modificar el código del `selectC()` ni el `ngFor`

Comment: :o funciona pero ¿cómo? ¿si necesito hacer mas peticiones dentro de este for tienen que ser siempre al final? Muchas gracias por tu tiempo

Comment: last regresa si es el último, ósea que se hará cuando sea la última, ¿En el oninit lo hace al iniciar y necesita hacerlo una vez cargue todo?

Comment: Agregué la explicación en la respuesta.

Comment: Estaba viendo que haciendo esto, se repite dos veces la misma acción. Puse una variable Booleana que se setea true la primera vez que entra

Comment: Agregué una nueva solución.

Comment: Nope, no funciona el ngAfterViewInit(), fue una de mis primera opciones ya que se supone que lo ejecuta una vez cargado el documento pero sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Pienso lo mismo también de la variable booleana, no se me ocurre algo diferente.